# Field Variable Not Persisting

Tags: kotlin

I am learning Kotlin. I am from a Java background, so some of my coding style may reflect that.

So I have written a Spring Boot application. I have written a class like this:

```
class CISCODeviceAdapter(private val deviceConnectionDetails: DeviceConnectionDetails) : DeviceAdapterBase {

    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)

    private val transactionID : String = ""

    private var sshConnection : SSHConnection? = null
    
    .
    .
    .
    .
    
    override fun executeCommand(commands: List<String>) : HashMap<String, String> {

        val deviceAdapterBase = CISCODeviceAdapter(deviceConnectionDetails)

        sshConnection = SSHConnection(deviceConnectionDetails.ipAddress, deviceConnectionDetails.port, deviceConnectionDetails.username, deviceConnectionDetails.password)

        deviceAdapterBase.createSession()

        val configurations = sshConnection!!.sendToShell(commands)

        deviceAdapterBase.endSession()

        logger.info("All commands run!")

        return configurations
    }
    
    .
    .
    .
    
     override fun createSession() {

        try {

            logger.debug("Creating a SSH connection to: ${deviceConnectionDetails.ipAddress}")

            sshConnection!!.connect("240")

            logger.debug("Connection created successfully.")

        } catch (e : ProtocolException) {

            logger.error("Unable to create the session to ${deviceConnectionDetails.ipAddress}.", e)

            throw ProtocolException(e.message)
        }
    }
    
    .
    .
    .
    .
}
```

So I initialize the `sshConnection` object in the `executeCommand()` function. But when the control comes to `createSession()` function, the `sshConnection` object is null.

Is there something extra that I have to do so that object value remains in place? I tried `lateinit` but even that didn't work. One thing, i did think of is, do I have to declare it in the parent interface `DeviceAdapterBase`?

Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: I don’t see any problems with your code. There are no surprising “gotchas” like you’re describing with Kotlin properties. But I don’t know Spring, and you cut a lot out of your class, so I don’t know if your code is being executed in the sequence you’re expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with kotlin. You can try to write your code in Java first. Then when you know it's working correctly, I suggest you let your IDE to convert it to kotlin.

Comment: Apologies. I thought it was something to do with Kotlin and my lack of knowledge in it. Turns out I was calling the methods in a wrong sequence.